# Two different queries returning the same object Spring Boot JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I created a Repository with 3 different queries. Each query returns a different result. But when it comes to mapping the first query result goes to the second query result. If I change the order of the queries the first result will be the result of the next query. I even tried to create two different Repositories

These are the result objects query:
[First Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTP9T.png)
[Second Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7nc2.png)

This is my First repository:

```
package com.springboot.first.app;


@Repository
public interface TotalSRepository extends JpaRepository<TotalEntity, Date>{


@Query(value= "select `data` , SUM(importo) as totaleContanti, 0 AS totaleBanca from spese s where (dataAss is null or dataAss > DATE(NOW()) ) and MONTH(s.`data` )= :mese and year(s.`data`) = :anno and s.tipoPag IN('CONTANTI', 'VOUCHER') group by s.`data`", 
        countQuery = "SELECT count(*) from spese s where (dataAss is null or DATE(NOW()) >= dataAss) and MONTH(s.`data` )= :mese and year(s.`data`) = :anno and s.tipoPag IN('CONTANTI', 'VOUCHER') group by s.`data`", 
        nativeQuery = true)
        List<TotalEntity> findSpeseTotalsContanti(@Param("mese") Integer mese, @Param("anno") Integer anno);

@Query(value= "select `data` , SUM(importo) as totaleBanca, 0 AS totaleContanti from spese s where (dataAss is null or dataAss > DATE(NOW()) ) and MONTH(s.`data` )= :mese and year(s.`data`) = :anno and s.tipoPag NOT IN('CONTANTI', 'VOUCHER') group by s.`data`", 
        countQuery = "SELECT count(*) from spese s where (dataAss is null or DATE(NOW()) >= dataAss ) and MONTH(s.`data` )= :mese and year(s.`data`) = :anno and s.tipoPag NOT IN('CONTANTI', 'VOUCHER') group by s.`data`", 
        nativeQuery = true)
        List<TotalEntity> findSpeseTotalsBanca(@Param("mese") Integer mese, @Param("anno") Integer anno);

}
```

This is the second repo

```
@Repository
public interface TotalRepository extends JpaRepository<TotalEntity, Date>{

@Query(value= "select `data`, (SUM(importoC) + SUM(importoT)) as totaleContanti, SUM(importoP) as totaleBanca from incassi i where MONTH(i.`data`) = :mese and YEAR(i.`data`) = :anno group by i.`data`", 
        countQuery = "SELECT count(*) from incassi i where MONTH(i.`data`) = :mese and YEAR(i.`data`) = :anno group by i.`data`", 
        nativeQuery = true)
        List<TotalEntity> findIncassiTotals(@Param("mese") Integer mese, @Param("anno") Integer anno);


}
```

This is the entity

```
@Entity
public class TotalEntity {
private Date data;
private Double totaleBanca; 
private Double totaleContanti; 


public TotalEntity() {
}


@Id
@Column(name = "data")
public Date getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Date data) {
    this.data = data;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "totalebanca")
public double getTotaleBanca() {
    return totaleBanca;
}

public void setTotaleBanca(double importoC) {
    this.totaleBanca = importoC;
}


@Basic
@Column(name = "totalecontanti")
public double getTotaleContanti() {
    return totaleContanti;
}

public void setTotaleContanti(double importoC) {
    this.totaleContanti = importoC;
}



}
```

I tried to execute the Hibernate logged query

```
Hibernate: select `data`, (SUM(importoC) + SUM(importoT)) as totaleContanti, SUM(importoP) as totaleBanca from incassi i where MONTH(i.`data`) = ? and YEAR(i.`data`) = ? group by i.`data`
Hibernate: select `data` , SUM(importo) as totaleBanca, 0 AS totaleContanti from spese s where (dataAss is null or dataAss > DATE(NOW()) ) and MONTH(s.`data` )= ? and year(s.`data`) = ? and s.tipoPag NOT IN('CONTANTI', 'VOUCHER') group by s.`data`
Hibernate: select `data` , SUM(importo) as totaleContanti, 0 AS totaleBanca from spese s where (dataAss is null or dataAss > DATE(NOW()) ) and MONTH(s.`data` )= ? and year(s.`data`) = ? and s.tipoPag IN('CONTANTI', 'VOUCHER') group by s.`data`
```

and the results are correct. But the mapped object in debug is the same. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've found is creating a different Entity for each query. Not the best option but it's all I've got right now.